# Error executing Anonymous Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting error as
**ORA-06550: line 21, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
   begin function pragma procedure**

while executing the Procedure,Kindly find the procedure below

```
declare
procedure p2;
procedure p3;
          procedure p1
                    is
                      begin
                           dbms_output.put_line('CAlling procedure P1');
                           p2;
                 end p1;
           procedure p2 is
                       begin
                            dbms_output.put_line('CAlling procedure P2');
                           p3;
                  end p2;
           procedure p3 is
                       begin
                            dbms_output.put_line('CAlling procedure P3');
                   end p3;
```

Plz help me in sorting out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare
   procedure p2;
   procedure p3;
   procedure p1 is
   begin
      dbms_output.put_line('CAlling procedure P1');
      p2;
   end p1;
   procedure p2 is
   begin
      dbms_output.put_line('CAlling procedure P2');
      p3;
   end p2;
   procedure p3 is
   begin
      dbms_output.put_line('CAlling procedure P3');
   end p3;
begin
   p1;
end;                   
/
```

Comment: Hi Dear,Thnks for ur reply.But still i m getting error as ORA-06550: line 20, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure